# Neo4J WITH clause gives no record when adding property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Just new to Neo4J and try to use WITH clause like the following :

```
MATCH (card:Card)-[:BELONGS]-(customer:Customer)
WITH customer, COUNT(DISTINCT card) as n_cards
WHERE n_cards > 3
RETURN customer
```

And it actually works well but when I add the `card` node type in the `WITH` clause, it gives nothing / empty when it was not empty with the previous query :

```
MATCH (card:Card)-[:BELONGS]-(customer:Customer)
WITH customer, COUNT(DISTINCT card) as n_cards, card # here the 'card' is added
WHERE n_cards > 3
RETURN customer
```

And the above query gives me nothing. I haven't filtered.

The final goal is to do that :

```
MATCH (card:Card)-[:BELONGS]-(customer:Customer)
WITH customer, COUNT(DISTINCT card) as n_cards, card # here the 'card' is added
WHERE (n_cards > 3 AND card.country == "US")
RETURN customer, card
```

Can you please explain why it gave empty result when I just added a node type and haven't even filtered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'card', in your query is not the label (which is  'Card' BTW) , but a placeholder for the node, since you did

```
(card:Card)
```

Furthermore, the COUNT() function will group by distinct customer/card combination, and since you added 'card', n_cards will always equal to 1, so n_cards > 3 will always be false.

```
MATCH (card:Card)-[:BELONGS]-(customer:Customer)
WHERE card.country = 'US'
WITH customer, COLLECT(DISTINCT card) AS cards
WHERE SIZE(cards) > 3 
RETURN customer, cards
```

would probably work if you want to see the customers who have  > 3 US cards

here is what you could do if you want to do further process the customer and cards..

```
// instead of RETURN , use WITH
WITH customer, cards   

// UNWIND the cards as individual nodes
UNWIND cards AS card    

// e,g, get transactions
WITH customer,card

OPTIONAL MATCH (card)-[t:TRANSACTION]->(m:Merchant)

RETURN customer.name AS customer,
                card.number AS cardNumber,
                t.amount AS amount,
                m.name AS merchant
```

Comment: Okay then but how to just pass value to the rest of the query ? 
Because on the Neo4j doc, there's written that : `The WITH clause allows query parts to be chained together, piping the results from one to be used as starting points or criteria in the next.` 
So imagine I want to chain with another match query after filtering the size, this means I can't ?

Comment: @LaSul imagine you want to do something with the customer and the cards ..

Comment: @LaSul imagine you want to do something with the customer and the cards .. and I am imagining a model of course..

``` 

// instead of RETURN , use WITH
WITH customer, cards   

// UNWIND the cards as individual nodes
UNWIND cards AS card    

// e,g, get transactions
WITH customer,card

OPTIONAL MATCH (card)-[t:TRANSACTION]->(m:Merchant)

RETURN customer.name AS customer,
                card.number AS cardNumber,
                t.amount AS amount,
                m.name AS merchant
              
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! My question was not properly asked tho! Apologies for that

Answer (score 2):

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) like `COUNT` use non-aggregating terms in the same `WITH` or `RETURN` clause as "grouping keys".

So, by adding `card` to the `WITH` clause, you are causing `n_cards` to always be 1, thereby causing the `WHERE` test to fail.

This should work:

```
MATCH (card:Card)-[:BELONGS]-(customer:Customer)
WHERE card.country = "US"
WITH customer, COLLECT(card) AS cards
WHERE SIZE(cards) > 3
RETURN customer, cards
```

Also, this query does not use `DISTINCT` when collecting the cards, since a `customer` will probably not have multiple `BELONGS` relationships to the same `card` node.

Comment: it seems we are very often more or less on the same page :)